# How to have full-width horizontal lines in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, text-formatting

How can I have full-width horizontal lines inserted between the lines of a long text? I do not want to use Ctrl+U to add underline to the text because it does not add lines to the empty spaces. Also adding lines via the "Insert Shapes" menu seems not accurate and somehow hard to do for multiple lines. Is there any straight forward way to add full-width line between the lines of a text?

I also thought of simulating this with a table and pasting my text in the rows of a table with bottom borders. The problem with this method is that all of the text is inserted in the first row of the table, while I want each line of my text to be in a separate row.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's the optimum desired vs. limitations of available solutions you're willing to settle for.  But to confirm a couple of points, by full width, you mean margin to margin? Between blocks of text, you want a single line that equally divides the gap?  Regarding the table approach, what is the problem with pasting the text into the rows you want, or splitting the text into additional rows?

Comment: I read this to mean that you want a margin-to-margin line under each line of text in a paragraph. I have searched for that solution and not found one. The answers below give you single lines wherever you manually place them or lines between *paragraphs* but not between lines *within* a paragraph.

Answer (score 18):

The following can be used to add lines of different types. Try any of these:

In a new line, enter

1. **Three hyphens** i.e. --- and then press Enter button.

**Result:**
[image]

2. **Three underscores** i.e. ___ and then press Enter button.

**Result:**[image]

3. **Three equals to sign** i.e. === and then press Enter button.

**Result:**[image]

4. **Three hashes** i.e. ###  and then press Enter button.

**Result:**[image]

5. **Three asterisks** i.e. *** and then press Enter button.

**Result:** [image]

6. **Three tildes** i.e. ~~~ and then press Enter button.

**Result:**[image]

Comment: And how can I add them between the lines of a long text? Should I really do this repeatedly?

Answer (score 6):

While the most popular answer will provide a solution for a line with no words, if you want to extend the underline under a current header, you need a different solution.

[image]

To do this you should write the header. Then you can highlight the complete line and click on the bottom border button.

[image]

This will give you an underline completely across the page.

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly simple:

1)  From the ribbon, select *Insert - Shapes - Line*
2)  Draw a line across the screen where you want it
3)  Right-click on the line and select *More Layout Options*
4)  Select the *Text Wrapping* tab
5)  Select *In Line With Text*

You will now have a line across the document that will stay in place relative to the text around it.

You state in the question that Insert Shapes is hard for multiple lines.  Not so if you select the *In Line With Text* option.
Note that the default is *In Front of Text* which is probably where you are finding the difficulty.  This option does not move the line with the text as it is edited.

Comment: Well, I was looking for a more automatic approach. What if I have 1000 lines? Should I copy and paste this shape 1000 times below each line of the text?

Comment: To do it for every line, you are probably better off defining a new style.